# Cron Editor not showing radio button

Tags: html, angular, cron

I'm using the Cron-Editor [Cron-Editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cron-editor) functionality wise it is working perfectly fine but on the daily tab if I select options the radio button is not marked with the items selected [image]. how to display or mark the radio button with the items selected.

**HTML :**

```
<cron-editor [(cron)]="cronExpression" [disabled]="isCronDisabled" [(options)]="cronOptions">Cron here...</cron-editor>
```

**TS :**

```js
    public cronExpression = '4 3 2 12 1/1 ? *';
    public isCronDisabled = false;
    public cronOptions: CronOptions = {
    formInputClass: 'form-control cron-editor-input',
    formSelectClass: 'form-control cron-editor-select',
    formRadioClass: 'cron-editor-radio',
    formCheckboxClass: 'cron-editor-checkbox',

    defaultTime: "10:00:00",

    hideMinutesTab: true,
    hideHourlyTab: false,
    hideDailyTab: false,
    hideWeeklyTab: false,
    hideMonthlyTab: true,
    hideYearlyTab: true,
    hideAdvancedTab: true,

    use24HourTime: true,
    hideSeconds: true
  };
```

Comment: Hi, sorry this isn't an answer, but I'm working with ngx cron editor and I'm having problems, I can display it but all fields are not editable...

Comment: actually functionally it is working fine the thing is i am not able to see the radio button marked. still this issue isn't solved i am looking for answers.